# Difference between single and double bracket in calling columns

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I'm in the process of learning R and hoped for some clarification on something.

Given this dataframe:

```
myDataset <- data.frame("IDs" = rep(1:10,each = 5),
                        "session" = rep(1:5, times = 10), 
                        "IV" = rnorm(50),
                        "DV" = rnorm(50))
```

What different uses would calling the first column from this dataframe have based on whether you used one set of brackets:

`myDataset[1]`

Or two sets of brackets:

`myDataset[[1]]`

They both give the same information, one in the form of the numbers listed in rows and the other in its original column form.

I'm just trying to understand why I might want to use one over the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `data.frame` is a `list` with columns of equal length.  By using `[[`, we extract the column as a `vector`, while with `[`, get a `data.frame` with single or multiple columns. Another option to return a `vector` with `[` is to specify the `,` to indicate explicitly that it is a column index and by default then the `drop = TRUE` gets triggered for `data.frame`

```
myDataset[, 1]
```

If we still want a data.frame single column

```
myDataset[, 1, drop = FALSE]
```